# Creating a Live Memory Dump to Non-System Disk

Tags: memory, crash, dump

Note: This might be impossible with my setup and stock software/OS, too difficult to be worthwhile, and/or require custom software to be created.  But, it would be useful for some people at times:

- **Windows 10 version 1709 on Drive C:** (I have avoided the mandated updates by merely only allowing 5-8 GB of free space on Drive C:\ System Drive.)
- **NO page file on C:\  .**(Only 5-8 GB Free, so no room)
- **Page file on Drive F:.**  ~17 GB (To support 16 GB of Physical RAM)

**I want to run some program that will simply create a copy of all 16 GB of RAM to a file name and drive location that I specify, not necessarily on Drive C:\system, and to do this dump and to keep running this Windows session and not crash, if possible.**

With a standard Windows Dump which includes Sysinternals tools, as I understand it, even if I do a forced crash, it will require a PAGE file that is 1MB greater than the RAM.  [(How to create a full memory dump)](https://support.symantec.com/us/en/article.howto31321.html).   Fine, I've done that with a Drive F:\PAGEFILE of 17 GB.

Problem is, once I crash, I think it will write all the RAM to my PAGE file on Drive F: and then what??  Normally, the page file would be located on Drive C:\, the same place as my system drive for Windows.  After it re-purposes the use of the page file into a dump file, it then "copies the file" into a DMP file and  places it into the Windows Folder.

But, what it is really doing is to rename the file, and then move the file location to a Windows System folder.  In my case, it can't just rename it to put it into the Windows folder, isnce it is located on a separate volume.  It must fully copy the file from one partition to the other (Drive C:\Windows) and there is not space for a 16 GB file on my C:.  So, what will it do??  Will it create a folder on drive F:\ instead?  Then create a Windows folder there on F:\? and then create a new page file on F:\?  Or, will it try to really copy it to C:\Windows\ ?

**So what do I plan for this file?**  I want to "browse through it" to see if some of the text I composed is still there, and then recover my work.  Today I had a very annoying app that crashed.  It was a Skype plugin for Chrome, and I was composing a long text there.  The screen "crashed", which erased a large part of my text when it refreshed the screen.  In the past, I've recovered data this way from RAM, and/or temp files.  This can also be used for forensics use, while the system is running.

Comment: Have you looked into LiveKD? Note you need to install Debugging Tools for Windows to get Windbg.

Comment: I did look "at it".  but, not in enough detail to use it.  Since my need wasn't urgent or at least critical, I got a bit lazy and just decided to ask and seek a "simple solution".  I miss some of the tool kits I've had and used in the past, where you could literally watch the bytes change on the fly, just by opening an app.  At the time, I could specify a memory range and turn it into a named file, and I was hoping I could still do that.

Comment: Well `livekd -o E:\dump.dmp` would probably do what you need.  When you open it in WinDbg, it will declare the dump to be: `Kernel Complete Dump File: Full address space is available`